# BeautifulSoup [python] not reading contents from the <td> tags after a particular point

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been using this small piece of code to get the names and emails of the people listed on this url: https://www.stern.nyu.edu/faculty/search_name_form 
Now, up until the point where I am using `rows = soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr')`, everything seems to work fine. This code seems to read all the `<tr>` tags properly. However, when I enter the `for` loop and print the arrays where I am storing names and emails, I get an output with a lot `None`.
The code:

```
try:
  source = rq.get('https://www.stern.nyu.edu/faculty/search_name_form')
  source.raise_for_status()
  soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html.parser')
  rows = soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr')
  names = [None]*len(rows)
  email = [None]*len(rows)
  i = 0
  for row in rows:
      names[i] = row.find_all('td')[0].a.text
      email[i] = row.find_all('td')[2].a.text
      i=i+1
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
  
print(names)
print(email)
```

The output:

```
['Acharya, Viral V.', ... , None, None]
['vva1@stern.nyu.edu', ..., None, None]
```

Along with the error message:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

If I just try `print(rows[len(rows)-1])`, it prints the contents of the last `<tr>` tag perfectly so I do not follow what exactly is going wrong here. 
I appreciate all and any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see here, some of the professors don't have email id so that is why when you try to get text from empty , you are getting that error.

This might be helpful

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

try:
  source = requests.get('https://www.stern.nyu.edu/faculty/search_name_form')
  source.raise_for_status()
  soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html.parser')
  rows = soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr')
  names = [None]*len(rows)
  email = [None]*len(rows)
  i = 0
  for row in rows:
      names[i] = row.find_all('td')[0].a.text if (row.find_all('td')[0].find_all('a')) else ''
      email[i] = row.find_all('td')[2].a.text if (row.find_all('td')[2].find_all('a')) else ''
      i=i+1
      
except Exception as e:
  print(e)

print(names)
print(email)
```

Comment: Also nice solution validating if `<a>` exists  -  You can shorten it to `if (row.find_all('td')[2].a) else ''`

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

You try to find the text of the `<a>` with `row.find_all('td')[0].a.text` that is okay, but if there is no `<a>` in the `<td>` you will get the error.

#### Solution

Cause the email is the only content in this `<td>`just grab the text from `<td>`

`row.find_all('td')[0].text`

#### Solution more structured

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.stern.nyu.edu/faculty/search_name_form'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')

data={'contacts':[]}
for row in soup.select('tbody tr'):
    
    data['contacts'].append({'name':row.select('td')[0].get_text(strip=True),
                             'email':row.select('td')[2].get_text(strip=True)
                            })
data
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the *a* and/or *text* attributes are missing from some *td*s. You could make your code more robust with something like this:-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def isvalid(td):
    return hasattr(td, 'a') and hasattr(td.a, 'text')

try:
    source = requests.get('https://www.stern.nyu.edu/faculty/search_name_form')
    source.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml')
    names = []
    email = []
    for row in soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr'):
        td = row.find_all('td')
        if len(td) > 2:
            if isvalid(td[0]) and isvalid(td[2]):
                names.append(td[0].a.text)
                email.append(td[2].a.text)
    print(names)
    print(email)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from lxml import html
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate
page = requests.get('https://www.stern.nyu.edu/faculty/search_name_form')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)  
rows=[]
for i in range(len(tree.xpath('//*[@id="faculty"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a/text()'))):
  xpa=f"//*[@id='faculty']/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[1]/a/text()"
  x1a=f"//*[@id='faculty']/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[3]/a/text()"
  c="".join(tree.xpath(xpa))
  d="".join(tree.xpath(x1a))
  row = [c,d]
  rows.append(row)
filename = "data.csv"
fields = ['Name', 'Email']
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

Output:

```
+-----+-----------------------------+----------------------------------+
|     | Name                        | Email                            |
|-----+-----------------------------+----------------------------------|
|   0 | nan                         | nan                              |
|   1 | Acharya, Viral V.           | vva1@stern.nyu.edu               |
|   2 | Adamson, Allen              | apa1@stern.nyu.edu               |
|   3 | Afsar Melemetci, Beril      | ba2201@stern.nyu.edu             |
|   4 | Albanese, Tommaso M.        | talbanes@stern.nyu.edu           |
|   5 | Aleszczyk, Aleksander       | aleszczyk@stern.nyu.edu          |
|   6 | Alter, Adam                 | ala8@stern.nyu.edu               |
|   7 | Altman, Edward I.           | eia1@stern.nyu.edu               |
|   8 | Altman, Steven A.           | saa558@stern.nyu.edu             |
|   9 | Amihud, Yakov               | ya1@stern.nyu.edu                |
|  10 | Anthony, Callen             | ca85@stern.nyu.edu               |
|  11 | Armony, Mor                 | ma67@stern.nyu.edu               |
|  12 | Arora, Amitabh              | aarora@stern.nyu.edu             |
|  13 | Arriaga, Manuel             | mad438@stern.nyu.edu             |
|  14 | Assael, Henry               | ha1@stern.nyu.edu                |
|  15 | Aviv, Yossi                 | ya27@stern.nyu.edu               |
|  16 | Ayala, Ricardo E.           | rayala2@stern.nyu.edu            |
|  17 | Baker, Richard              | rb3873@stern.nyu.edu             |
|  18 | Bakos, Yannis               | yb6@stern.nyu.edu                |
+-----+-----------------------------+----------------------------------+
```